# How to add only values of an objects from MongoDB to an array in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

So here's an example of what my collection looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5tES.png

When I run the command:

```
db.Try.find({Type: "Electronic"}, {Brand: 1, _id: 0})
```

My result is:

```
[
  { Brand: 'Apple' }
  { Brand: 'Dell' }
  { Brand: 'Samsung' }
]
```

I want to put the above data into a NodeJS array so that I can display it in HTML form.

When I try my output is:

```
[
  { Brand: 'Apple' },
  { Brand: 'Dell' },
  { Brand: 'Samsung' }
]
```

But expected output is:

```
['Apple','Dell','Samsung']
```

***How can I get those results??***

Comment: Add example of your data as code, and not as image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `map` the output from MongoDB:

```js
const mongodb_output = [
  { Brand: 'Apple' },
  { Brand: 'Dell' },
  { Brand: 'Samsung' }
];

const result = mongodb_output.map(item => item.Brand);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you did and how this worked??

Comment: Each item in `mongodb_output` is an object. So, it will map each item to his `Brand` property. That way, each object will become a string with a value of his `Brand` property.